# cannot read in image in colour in opencv python

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

I have just started to use Opencv using python in windows(PyCharm IDE).
I tried to read a color image. But it got displayed in Grayscale. So I tried to convert it as below:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('C:\Ai.jpg', 0)
b,g,r = cv2.split(img)
rgb = cv2.merge([r,g,b])
cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.imshow('rgb image',rgb)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But i am getting an error:

> "b, g, r = cv2.split(img) ValueError: need more than 1 value to
>   unpack"

Can you guys please help me out?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem in the second line of your code `img = cv2.imread('C:\Ai.jpg', 0)`, as per the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html#read-an-image), `0` value corresponds to `cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE`, This is the reason why you are getting a grayscale image. You may want to change it to `1` if you want to load it in RGB color space or `-1` if you want to include any other channel like `alpha` channel which is encoded along with the image.

And `b,g,r = cv2.split(img)` was raising an error because `img` at that point of time is a grayscale image which had only one channel, and it is impossible to split a 1 channel image to 3 respective channels.

Your final snippet may look like this:

```
import cv2
# Reading the image in RGB mode
img = cv2.imread('C:\Ai.jpg', 1)

# No need of following lines:
# b,g,r = cv2.split(img)
# rgb = cv2.merge([r,g,b])
# cv2.imshow('rgb image',rgb)

# Displaying the image
cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation! I understand now!

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

**Read and convert image into RGB format:**

If you have a color image and reading it using OpenCV. First, convert it in RGB colour format

```
image = cv2.imread(C:\Ai.jpg')                 #cv2 reading image in BGR
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) #convert it into RGB format
```

**To display it we can use cv2.imshow, matplotlib or PIL as follows**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
from PIL import Image
```

Now print using matplotlib:

```
plt.imshow(image)
```

print using PIL

```
Image.fromarray(image)
```