# An alternative to read image from scipy to cv2

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

the following python script I want to convert using opencv python, how do I make it converted?

script:  scipy.misc.imread(path, mode='RGB').astype(np.float)

I want to convert it using cv2 and what would be alternative for astype(np.float) with this?

```
import cv2
import scipy.misc

img = scipy.misc.imread(path, mode='RGB').astype(np.float)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `cv2.imread`, convert color format from BGR to RGB, and convert to `float`:

```
path = 'chelsea.png'

ref_img = scipy.misc.imread(path, mode='RGB').astype(np.float)

img = cv2.imread(path)  # Read input imgae
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)  # Convert color format form BGR to RGB (OpenCV default is BGR).
img = img.astype(np.float)  # Convert ot float

print(np.all(img == ref_img))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
img = cv2.imread(path, -1).astype(np.float)
```

Comment: in this link flag for rgb reading is 1 but given -1 what is right?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32420399/cannot-read-in-image-in-colour-in-opencv-python

Comment: the number `-1` means "unchanged", no conversions or whatever

Comment: I want to read image in rgb mode it means even input image binary or grayscale it has to be read in rgb mode, thanks that comment also being helpful I think the following script will be ok  img = cv2.imread(path, 1).astype(np.float)